# Understanding read syscall

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm reading `man read` manual page and discovered that it was possible to read less then the desired number of bytes passed in as a parameter:

> It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
>   requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are
>   actually available right now (maybe because we were close to
>   end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a
>   termi‐nal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

I have the following situation:

1. Some process moved a file into a directory I'm listening to `IN_MOVED_TO` inotify events.
2. I receive a `IN_MOVED_TO` event, open a file and start reading it till the EOF is reached
3. No other processes modify the moved at `1.` file (After it is moved it is left unchanged all the time)

Is it guaranteed that if `read` returns the number of bytes read less then I requested then the next call to `read` will return 0? I mean the situation like 'reading 1 000 000 000 by a single bytes for a gigabyte file' is forbidden by the documentation

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Shawn So is it theoretically possible to read a 1GB file by a single byte  `10000000000` times even if I have a 2MB buffer and specified to read 2MB?

Comment: If you want to read a file a single char at a time, you can. It's going to be a lot more efficient if you use stdio instead, or otherwise implement buffering so you don't have to call `read()` once per char, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that if read returns the number of bytes read less then I requested then the next call to read will return 0?

No, not in practice. It should be true if the file system is entirely POSIX compliant, but many of them are not (in corner cases). In particular NFS (see [nfs(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nfs.5.html)) and [FUSE](http://Filesystem_in_Userspace) or proc (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) are not exactly POSIX compliant.

So in practice I strongly recommend handling the "`read` returns a smaller number of bytes than wanted case", even if you are right to believe that it should not happen. Handling that "impossible" case should be easy for you.

Notice also that [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities don't work with bizarre filesystems like NFS, proc, FUSE, ... Think also of corner cases like, inside an Ext4 file system, a symlink to an NFS file,; or bind mounts, etc...

Comment: But is it true for `ext4`? So in general it depends on the filesystem implementation, right?

Comment: Probably yes. But you still want to write some code which should work with NFS etc... I don't recommend coding something which would break on bizarre filesystems

Comment: Also, Linux limits all read and write syscalls to less than 2 GiB (slightly less than 2³⁰ bytes) to avoid filesystem bugs/issues wrt. signed 32-bit integers.